# How define location of CALayer in the UIView during movement

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, calayer, cabasicanimation

I have want to make an application where apples fall down from the tree and user can catch it with the basket. Basket starts moving when I touch the screen so it moves in that direction - but slowly. For this I use

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch* t = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [t locationInView:self.view];
    if(p.y <self.view.frame.size.height-50)
    {
        p.y = self.view.frame.size.height-50;
    }

    CABasicAnimation *basketmovementAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    [basketmovementAnimation setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:[[self.basketLayer presentationLayer]position]]];
    [basketmovementAnimation setDuration:3.0];

    [self.basketLayer setPosition:p];
    [self.basketLayer addAnimation:basketmovementAnimation forKey:@"basket"];
}
```

So the question is how to get coordinates of "basket" during movement? I need it to compare with the coordinates of fallen apples. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is what a game framework like SpriteKit is intended to be used for. Though you can create the game using UIKit, SpriteKit will let you determine the location of your views for each frame presented to the user as well as let you define collision interactions between objects like apples and baskets.

Comment: @ZeMoon Thank you, but currently i am not using these frameworks, just CABasicAnimation, how in this case define it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CALayer has a method for this.

```
- (id)presentationLayer
```

From the  CALayer Class Reference

> The layer object returned by this method provides a close
>   approximation of the layer that is currently being displayed onscreen.
>   While an animation is in progress, you can retrieve this object and
>   use it to get the current values for those animations.

Comment: Thank you I will try to use this method.